# Как увеличивать массив на 1 в Си/С++?

Tags: c++, c

Как увеличивать массив на 1 каждый раз, когда появляется новый элемент? Например, в векторе можно сделать так:

```
std::vector<int> abc = {1, 2, 3}; //Вектор на 3 элемента
abc.push_back(10); //Теперь размер вектора увеличился на 1. Его размер стал 4
```

Я не знаю, как подобное реализовать в массивах(пишу свой стэк).

Comment: Никак, размер массива задается во время создания.

Comment: Но в векторах это же как-то реализовано. Вектор это тот же массив, но со своими сладостями.

Comment: В векторе при исчерпании места создается новый массив.

Comment: О, вы ответили на мой вопрос. Спасибо большое =D
Теперь я знаю, что делать, ахах

Comment: Увеличивать количество выделенной памяти на 1 слишком дорого, тот же вектор выделяет память с запасом и у него помимо size есть capacity

Comment: Обычно при использовании массивов главное знать сколько именно памяти вам нужно. Статика всегда лучше и быстрее динамики, если вы расчитали что 1000 элементов вам гарантировано хватит - то лучше создать массив на 1000. При небольших размерах так лучше. Для универсальности - можно использовать "динамику". Если есть зависимость, по которой можно расчитать по входным данным рамер массива - то лучше один раз запросить нужный размер.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Расширение динамического массива путем реалокации памяти:

```
int *array = new int [5] {1,2,3,4,5};
array = (int *) realloc (array,sizeof(int) * 6); // Расширили массив на 1 элеммент с 5 до 6
```

Comment: А если надо уменьшить на 1, то надо просто поделить на 6?

Comment: @Silencer, нет, такая штука не прокатит.

Comment: Я пишу функцию pop() в своем стэке(который сам пишу). Как ее реализовать?

Если учитывать, что у меня есть динамический массив и ваш код в качестве "расширителя" для места.
P.S. pop() удаляет последний элемент из стэка

Comment: Ну как бы динамический массив вовсе не массив, а все таки область памяти. И там свои приколы. Можно костыльно удалить, но не стоит. Расширять - пожалуйста, уменьшать... Ну во всяком случае я не знаю прям такого простого метода. Лучше всё таки векторы, если хочется гибкости.

Comment: Это очень плохой ответ. Во-первых потенциальная потеря данных из-за кода `a = realloc(a, ...)`. В случае ошибки `realloc` вернёт `NULL` и вы потеряете всё. Во-вторых увеличение массива только на один элемент приводит к очень низкой производительности.

Comment: Это очень упрощённый случай. В реальности нужно учесть приведеное выше. Обычно используется доп поле capacity которое квантуется так, что бы елементы занимали размер кратно размеру страницы памяти либо более большой порции памяти. Учесть что relloc может выдать NULL.

Comment: @Silencer, `realloc` будет работать и для уменьшения стека. Избегайте только измения размера на константу, можно увеличивать массив в два раза, если место кончилось и уменьшать если вы занимаете только четверть места. Важно: не надо уменьшать и увеличивать в одинаковое число раз - буду проблемы с производительностью когда размер стека пляшет вблизи границы где происходить реаллокации.